# How to remove attribute when 2 checkboxes are checked

Tags: jquery

Trying to remove disabled attribute, when 2 checkboxes are all checked.

This is what I tried below, but not working well.

```
<script>
$('#userAgree, #privacyAgree').change(function () {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $(".btn-confirm").removeAttr("disabled");
    }
    else {
        $(".btn-confirm").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }
});
</script>
```

What did I missed ?

Comment: Use `.prop('disabled', true)` instead of `attr` (and `.prop('disabled', false)` for the opposite). Also, `$(this).is(':checked')` only checks the currently changing checkbox, not both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#userAgree, #privacyAgree').click(function () {
    $(".btn-confirm").prop("disabled", $('#userAgree, #privacyAgree').filter(":checked").length !== 2);
});
```

Setting the property instead of the attribute allows you to use `true` or `false`, and the button needs to be disabled as long as not both checkboxes are checked.

Using `click` as the event works better than `change`.

Comment: thank you this works perfectly ;)